# Morphisms in the category $\text{Comp}$ are abelian groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, category-theory, definition

I'm reading Rotman's Introduction to Algebraic Topology and he states that the set of morphisms between two chain complexes in the category $\text{Comp}$ (defined in the box below) is in fact an abelian group.

> $(S_*, \partial) \in \text{Obj Comp}$, where $(S_*, \partial)$ means
>   chain complex.
>
> Hom$(S_*', S_*) = \{ \text{Set of all chain maps between $S_*'$ and
>  $S_*$}\}$
>
> Composition is defined as: $\{f_n\} \circ \{g_n \} = \{f_n \circ
>  g_n\}$, for chain maps $f=\{f_n\}$, and $g=\{g_n\}$.

He states that if $f=\{f_n\}$ and $g=\{g_n\} \in $ Hom $(S_*', S_*)$, then , $f + g \in$ Hom$(S_*', S_*)$.  I'm trying to prove to myself that this is a group, but what does this operation represent?  What is $\{f_n\} + \{g_n\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{f_n\} + \{g_n\}$ is the family of morphism of abelian groups $S'_n \to S_n, x \mapsto f_n(x) + g_n(x)$.

Comment: What does $f_n(x) + g_n(x)$ mean?

Comment: By definition $S_n$ is an abelian group (or a $R$-module depending of your definition) right ?

Comment: Yes, $S_n$ is a free abelian group.  So if $f,g: X \rightarrow Y$ and $f_n ,g_n: S_n(X) \rightarrow S_n(Y)$, then $f_n(x \in S_n(X)) + g_n(x \in S_n(X)) = \sigma_{f_n(x)} + \sigma_{g_n(x)}$ where $\sigma \in S_n(Y)$?

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by $\sigma$. The situation is simple : you have morphism $f_n, g_n : S_n \to S_n'$. You define a morphism $(f_n + g_n)(x)$ as $(f_n + g_n)(x) = f_n(x) + g_n(x)$. It is by immediate definition a morphism of groups (and also a chain complex morphism).

Comment: I meant:  If $f_n, g_n : S_n \rightarrow S_n'$, then is $f_n(x) + g_n(x) \in S'_n$ as it's just a linear sum of two elements of $S_n'$?  And therefore $\{f_n\} + \{g_n\} = \{f_n(x) + g_n(x) \in S_n': x \in S_n\}$?

Comment: Yes exactly, and this how you can define the sum of two morphisms of chain complex.

Comment: $f_n + g_n$ is the morphism; $(f_n + g_n)(x)$ is the value of that morphism at $x$. This comment thread is getting things mixed up; in particular, the formula @OliverG wrote isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$\{ f_n \} + \{  g_n \} = \{ f_n + g_n \} $$

That is, the $n$-th component of the sum of chain morphisms is the sum of the $n$-th components of the two terms.

---

If you've never seen the a sum of morphisms, then I will presume you are working in the special case of chain complexes of abelian groups.

Addition is a standard operation on abelian group homomorphisms, and is defined pointwise: if $u,v : G \to H$ are abelian group homomorphisms, then $u+v : G \to H$ is a group homomorphism as well, with values given by

$$ (u + v)(g) = u(g) + v(g) $$

Comment: Why did you answer since another answer was already accepted ? (Don't take it as aggressiveness, I am just curious).